# IOS google admob test device and App Store submission

Tags: ios, admob

I use google admob and show full screen advertisement like this..

```
GADInterstitial *interstitial = [[GADInterstitial alloc] initWithAdUnitID:@"ca-app-pub-798660655353089081/4370438050"]; //as an example
interstitial.delegate = self;

GADRequest *request = [GADRequest request];
request.testDevices = @[@"241ac0dsdf2c212ea860b2d9b77cf69d92" ]; //as an example
[interstitial loadRequest:request];
return interstitial;
```

In order to show, I show like this.

```
if ([self.interstitial isReady]) 
{
       [self.interstitial presentFromRootViewController:self];
}
```

Problem is that when apple test my app, they don't see advertisement. I also don't know their UDID to show advertisement on their device. As a result, they reject my app and said my app doesn't have any advertisement. How shall I do for that? Is there any method that I can show advertisement on other device?

Comment: Why do you submit the app with the test device property set?

Comment: Where is the code to display the ad? You should see this https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/ios/interstitial

Comment: If I set test device, they won't be able to see?

Comment: I guess the test device is your own device. According to google admob docs, you can send your app including your test device. So that's not the problem. However, I have another question, do you see the test interstitial in your own device?

Comment: yes. I saw in my device. Just that other people doesn't see because i haven't put their UDID. How shall I do so that apple tester can see?